# Auto increment column i JDO, GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have a data class with some fields, one is a URL that I consider the PK, if I add a new item (do a new sync) and save it it should overwrite the item in the database if it's the same URL. But I also need a "normal" Long id that is incremented for every object in the database and for this one I always get null unless I tags it as a PK, how can a get this incrementation but not have the column as my PK?

```
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long _id;
@Persistent
private String _title;
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent
private String _url;
```

/Viktor

Comment: If the URL is a key, why do you also need a long?

Comment: When requesting the object from a webpage I don't want to add the full url to the query string but just a id for the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
@PrimaryKey
private String _url;

@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE)
private Long _id;
```

Populate `_url` with your key and leave `_id` unset when saving your object. `_id` should then be automatically populated, though I am not sure whether it is going to be a sequential-id or not.

Information source: [official Google AppEngine wiki](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html).

Comment: Ok, that dose not work as I try to set _url to a "unencoded string" and it wants a encoded string so my question then is what is a encoded string? I have tried searching but not found anything about this. Have also tried to base64 encode the string but that did not help.

Comment: I see. Encoded string is a string representation of the `Key` class, that can be converted to and from string using `KeyFactory`'s `keyToString()` and `stringToKey()` methods, but I guess that is not what you want. It appears that you can use custom string keys by just specifying `@PrimaryKey` annotation. I have modified my answer, try it out.

Comment: Actually I also bumped into the same problem. The answer I provided seems to work. Make sure you set `valueStrategy` to `SEQUENCE` in order to get sequentially incrementing ids.

Comment: Thanks! It works, could have sworn I had tried that before I posted the question here but apparently not :)